# Getting the value in the textfield in IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, xcode-ui-testing

I am new to Swift and x-code. I'm currently developing an app where there is only one textbox and one submit button.

I am writing a test case which is like this- "Whenever i click the submit button, the text which is given by me in the text field should be validated."

How can i get the **text** from the textbox when i click the submit button? while running the test case

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: you can get `textField` value on `UIButton` click by `textField.text!`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `IBOutlet` for that `textField` and connect it in the storyboard (See attached file)

```
@IBOutlet weak private var textField: UITextField!
```

And use `textField.text` to get text file value in your IBAction that handle tap event

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To find out when the button is clicked, you will have to define an Action for your button in some Target... usually your view controller.  Search Apple’s documentation for the “Target Action” design pattern and you should find tutorial information.

To get the value of a text field, you can simply get it’s text property.  However, to get a reference to the text field, your view controller will need an Outlet that references the text view.  In the documentation you can search for “Outkests” or IBOutlet to find tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

first create @IBOutlet of your text field and create @IBAction of submit button. and validate it in @IBAction like this :-

```
@IBOutlet weak var textfieldOutlet: UITextField!

@IBAction func submit(_ sender: UIButton)
{
  if textfieldOutlet.text?.isEmpty == False
  {
     print(textfieldOutlet.text);
  }
}
```

*set breakpoint on print value and you getvalue

Answer (score 0):

In UI tests, you can access the text from an `XCUIElement` representing a `UITextField` using the `value` property.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let textField = app.textFields.element
textField.typeText("test text")
let text = textField.value as? String // should be "test text"
```